# How to add a Firebase security rule for checking if logged in users email is in a list

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I try to add a security rule that should grant write access given that the logged in user is in a list within the record.

I.e. my "tournament" record has a List officials in where I put the emails of those that should be able to alter the tournament.

I don't get this to work so I guess that my rule has some error in it.

```
match /tournaments {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow write: if request.auth.token.email in resource.data['officials'];
}
```

Comment: It should be like `match /tournaments/{tournamentID}`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule you have written is has some missing syntax. The rule must be like mentioned below:

```
match /tournaments/{tournamentID} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow write: if request.auth.token.email in resource.data['officials'];
}
```

The `/tournaments/{tournamentID}` indicates that the rule will apply for all documents present in tournament collection and `{doc_id}` is a wild card to representing documents in that collection.